# Increasing array size in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have project and this is my code. I am expected to write a console application which finds the largest k numbers in a given file and prints these largest k numbers in descending order. My program should take the filename and k as input parameters from the user.

For example for the following file content:

```
3, 5, 12, 54, 12, 3, 654, 11, 46, 7, 3
```

The output for k = 3 should be:

```
654 54 46
```

---

```
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int i, size, p, maxim, k, n, j;

    int* a = new int[7000000];

    size = 7000000;
    ifstream file("7_million_numbers.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {

        for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1) 
            file >> a[i];

    }
    cout << "Enter the number: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (j = 1; j < n; j = j + 1) {
        for (k = 0; k < size - 1; k++) {
            maxim = a[k];
            p = k;
            for (i = k + 1; i < size; i++)
                if (a[i] > maxim) {
                    maxim = a[i];
                    p = i;
                }
            a[p] = a[k];
            a[k] = maxim;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " " << endl;

    system("pause");
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is not working. I had ".exe stopped working" problem. Is it because of an array size? Because text file which is reading by program has a 7 million numbers.

Comment: Have you tried it on a file which has less numbers?

Comment: "I had '.exe stopped working' problem." This is not a technical description of a problem. Step through this code in your debugger and figure out where the problem is; at the very least, you'll get a stack trace that includes the line number where the crash is occurring.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you asking about reallocating or changing an array size; or are you asking about finding largest numbers?

Comment: My advice? Start with `int* a = new int[4];` and work your way up to *a hundred billion*.

Comment: @Galik, "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.". So why did you do the same thing with your edit? "With great power comes great responsibility". Don't vote if don't respect other vote! (2 vs 1,). I add you do the list of vote problem, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339212/70761533.

Comment: @Stargateur I didn't do the same thing. The pending edit did not "respect the author's intention" in that it changed the original author's coding style. Rather than accept that I decided to keep the author's original coding style and simply fix the slight indentation problem.

Comment: @Galik "respect the author's intention", this is not what is write in the [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14708633). Do it properly. And I don't agree, the "original coding style" was very unclear. But, I will take more attention to this point in the future.

Comment: Isn't this what `std::partial_sort` is designed for or are you not allowed to use the std library?

Comment: Your compiler probably doesn't allocate enough space on the for an array of 7,000,000 `int`s. I think your tutor expects you to realise you should read through the file picking out only the k largest values. You can even keep track of the kth element to make insertion easier or use `std::set<>`.

Comment: Oh, and start by finding the top 5 values out of a file of 20 numbers. Then scale up rapidly. Your debug and fix cycles will be shorter. Include a test case where the kth smallest value is the last value in a file.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple solution to your problem, you can sort the given numbers in descending order before taking the input of the numbers to be shown, after sorting you can ask user "How many greatest numbers to be shown" and when  you show the sorted result it will automatically show the greatest n numbers.

Instead of int make it long int.

```
int main() {
int i, size, p, maxim, k, n, j;

long int* a = new long int[7000000];

size = 7000000;
ifstream file("7_million_numbers.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{

    for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1) 
        file >> a[i];

}
cout << "Enter the number: " << endl;
cin >> n;

for(j=0;j<size;j++){
    for(k=j;k<size;k++){
         if(a[j]<a[k]){
            int temp;
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[k];
            a[k] = temp;
         }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

    cout << a[i] << " " << endl;

system("pause");
delete[] a;
return 0;



}
```

Comment: Int can (probably in OP's case too) hold values of up to `2147M` which is way larger than OP's `7M`. Under Windows the implementations of `long int` and `int` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're only doing one lookup per run.  I would think that you wouldn't need to store all the numbers in memory just the kth largest.  to do this a `set<int>` would work well:

```
void FindKthLargest( istream& fileIn , ostream& userOut, istream& userIn )
{
    int k = 0;
    userOut << "Enter the k number: ";
    userIn >> k;
    set<int> largetNums;
    int temp = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        if ( fileIn >> temp )
        {
            largetNums.emplace( temp );
        }
        else
        {
            userOut << "Number is too big\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    while ( fileIn >> temp )
    {
        set<int>::iterator lowest = largetNums.begin();
        if ( temp > *lowest )
        {
            largetNums.emplace( temp );
            largetNums.erase( lowest );
        }
    }
    for ( auto i : largetNums )
    {
        userOut << i;
    }
}
```